# Parallel.Invoke Not working as expected in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, parallel-processing

I am calling a SSIS Package from my C# code. The package processes one by one file and deletes it from a particular folder.

As the package processes one file by one, I want show the progress in a progressbar.

I have written this function to fetch the progress:

```
private void fileIteration(string folderPath)
{
    int initialFileCount, fileCount, processCount;        
    initialFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate (){ progressBar1.Value = initialFileCount;}));

    if (initialFileCount > 0)
    {
        fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;

        while (fileCount != 0)
        {
            // Thread.Sleep(2000);
            fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
            processCount = initialFileCount - fileCount;
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { progressBar1.Increment(processCount); }));
            initialFileCount = initialFileCount + processCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Since both tasks should execute in parallel, I am invoking like this

```
  Parallel.Invoke(

            () => fileIteration(folderPath),// for prgressbar
            () => results = package.Execute()); // for calling package
```

However both are not working together for me. I tried to keep 100 files and kept folder open so as to crosscheck the fast process is making me to unable to see the progressbar. It is not the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: The progress bar need to be the sum of the files processed by both parallel tasks.  How are you getting the sum?

Comment: @jdweng one task is actually to check the progress.The logic for progress bar is written in fileIteration. The other is to execute the package. This will delete one by one processed files.

Comment: Is there a way to add custom events to your SSIS package? I mean in this case you could handle them using eventListener and update your progress bar as soon as a file has been deleted. More info about events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-local-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

The [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke) is a blocking method. If you are calling it from the UI thread, a deadlock will occur, because the `fileIteration` method calls back the UI thread in order to update the progress bar. So everything will get stuck.

> This method does not return until each of the provided operations has completed, regardless of whether completion occurs due to normal or exceptional termination.

My suggestion is to ditch both the `Parallel.Invoke` and the `Invoke(new MethodInvoker` shenanigans, and embrace the [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/):

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int filesCountInit = await GetFilesCountAsync();
    if (filesCountInit == 0) return;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    var ssisTask = Task.Run(() => _package.Execute());
    while (!ssisTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        await Task.WhenAny(ssisTask, Task.Delay(1000));
        int filesCount = await GetFilesCountAsync();
        int percentDone = Math.Max(0, 100 - (filesCount * 100 / filesCountInit));
        progressBar1.Value = percentDone;
    }
    if (ssisTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
    var results = await ssisTask;
    // Display the results
}

private Task<int> GetFilesCountAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => Directory.GetFiles(
        _folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallel.Invoke does NOT ensure parallel execution.

[...]Executes each of the provided actions, POSSIBLY in parallel.[...]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netcore-3.1

Try spawning an explicit thread to ensure parallel execution of the progress monitor code piece.